# memcpy that doesn't really make sense to me

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I have some socket connection code that makes use of boost::asio which reads from a socket the first 5 chars, from which it can determine if the sent string was compressed using zlib library.  The project I'm currently doing is a rewrite of something existing, so I took some of the existing code and made it more C++ like, instead of C.  However in the code it has a call to `memcpy`, which to me seems entirely redundant, however if that call is not there, the call to `async_read` does never get called, which is what I don't get.  Why?  What is the purpose of this `memcpy` call and why does it need to be there, from all indicators?

```
/*check for zlib compression and then call handle_read_s which gets the rest of the data and decompresses if necessary.*/
/// buff is a vector<char>
/// tempbuff is a char[5]
void tcp_connection::handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& err, size_t bytes_transferred, endpoint_ptr ptr)
{
    unsigned long maxsz = 1024; //0xffffffff;
    size_t size = 1024;
    b_zlib = false;

    if (!err || err ==  boost::asio::error::message_size)
    {
        if (bytes_transferred >= 4)
        {
            if (tempbuff[0] == 'Z')
                b_zlib = true;

            //Remove 4 bytes & remove memcpy
            memcpy(&maxsz, &tempbuff[1], 4);   //removing this makes my code unworkable, I don't get it?
            buff.resize(maxsz);  //passing anything else here also kills it?!!
            boost::asio::async_read(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buff), boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_read_s, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred, ptr));
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you think, the `memcpy()` would be redundant? What other part of the code would do the same thing? Remember, the first parameter of `memcpy()` is the destination.

Comment: @Tilman, I seemed to have forgotten that it got the size of the to be gotten data, and I had a discussion with a coworker that seemed to indicate it was redundant, as he thought it was getting rid of those bytes and not getting a size. He does have more experience then me, so that he thought this worries me. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the `memcpy` is to render the code unportable,
and introduce awkward bugs when the code is compiled on another
machine.  What it does is set `maxsz` to some value depending on
what you just read.  Whether the value is correct depends on the
machine.  (If I can trust the names, there is also undefined
behavior is `bytes_transferred` is equal to 4.  And there will
be undefined behavior if you port to a machine where `unsigned
long` is 64 bits.)

Depending on the protocol, you should either use:

```
maxsz = static_cast<unsigned char>(tempbuff[1])
    | (static_cast<unsigned char>(tempbuff[2]) << 8)
    | (static_cast<unsigned char>(tempbuff[3]) << 16)
    | (static_cast<unsigned char>(tempbuff[4]) << 24);
```

or

```
maxsz = (static_cast<unsigned char>(tempbuff[1]) << 24)
    | (static_cast<unsigned char>(tempbuff[2]) << 16)
    | (static_cast<unsigned char>(tempbuff[3]) << 8)
    | static_cast<unsigned char>(tempbuff[4]);
```

(Change the type of `tempbuff` to `unsigned char[5]`, and you can
eliminate the `static_cast`.  This may require other changes
elsewhere, however.)

Also, the second `if` should almost certainly be:

```
if ( bytes_transferred > 4 )
```

, not `>=` (or alternatively `>= 5`).  Or the name shouldn't be
`bytes_transferred`.  Your code accesses all five bytes of
`tempbuff`.  (For that matter, I suspect that if
`bytes_transferred` isn't exactly 5, things will screw up.)

Comment: I appreciate your input, code unportable? why would anyone do that? Protocol is TCP.  As others have said, maxsz should contain the size of the buffer that is to be gotten next from the socket.

Comment: @Tony The Tiger If the protocol is TCP, the code as written will only work on a big-endian, 32 bit machine.  Something that practically doesn't exist any more.  (Unless there is additional code somewhere that you're not showing us.)  As to why someone would write unportable code here: ignorance (or naïvety), incompetence, or simply carelessness.  (The more or less obvious error in the test of `bytes_transferred` suggests a great deal of carelessness in the original code.)

Comment: I admit that the bytes_transferred was my doing and I guess that was due to my ignorance.  The memcpy came straight from the original code.

Comment: so which of the above of your suggestions should I use then? to make it work on 64bit architectures?

Comment: @Tony The Tiger Both will work correctly on all architectures; which one is correct depends on the format of the data you're reading.  If it is part of the TCP protocol (and not the payload), then the second is correct.  But if this were the case, the `'Z'` couldn't be there.

Answer (score 4):

This code is telling you the size of the buffer required.

```
memcpy(&maxsz, &tempbuff[1], 4);
```

And this code is resizing your buffer

```
buff.resize(maxsz);
```

Answer (score 1):

That code is essentially the same as the following, which I assume looks more familiar to you:

```
maxsz = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&tempBuff[1]);
// or possibly, depending on endianness, ...
maxsz = ntohl(*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&tempBuff[1]));
```

The difference is that using `memcpy` in the manner your code does is standard-compliant whereas using `reinterpret_cast` as shown here invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: but I was asking for why the memcpy should be there? why does it not work without it?

Comment: @Tony The Tiger : The invocation of `memcpy` sets the proper value of `maxsz`; why would you think this is optional or unnecessary?

Comment: can I do the same using std::copy?

Comment: Neither work here except in the very restricted case where the hardware happens to use the exact format that is present on the line.  Which is rarely the case: most protocols are big-endian; the most common hardware is little-endian.  And `unsigned long` is likely to be 8 bytes anyway.

Comment: @Tony The Tiger : Yes, I believe the following is technically standard-compliant: `char* maxszbuf = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&maxsz)); std::copy(&tempBuff[1], &tempBuff[1 + sizeof(unsigned long)], maxszbuf);`

Answer (score 0):

I think the first 4 bytes of tempbuff the size of buffer so it reads the first 4 bytes, determines the size of the buffer and then resizes the buffer to that size. Doing this in reinterpret_cast like ildjarn will make it more C++ like.

Comment: @Dani : The point of my post was, doing it using `reinterpret_cast` *looks* more like C++, but is actually illegal. Using `memcpy` here is actually the correct thing to do.

Comment: @Dani, you should reread ildjarn's answer carefully and consider amending your answer...

Comment: @James Kanze : To my knowledge, using `memcpy` in this fashion has defined behavior, unlike `reinterpret_cast`. (Aside from this code relying on `sizeof(unsigned long)` being `4`)

Comment: @ildjarn Sort of.  The behavior of both `reinterpret_cast` and `memcpy` is perfectly defined here... to depend in some very unspecified way on the contents of the `char` array, and the actual representation of `unsigned long`.  On most modern machines, `unsigned long` is 8 bytes: if you use the `reinterpret_cast`, you'll read uninitialized data for part of the `unsigned long`; if you use `memcpy` with length 4, you'll not initialize part of the `unsigned long`.  And even if the length of `unsigned long` is 4, you'll still get a value dependent on the byte order.

Comment: @James Kanze : §5.2.10/7 of the C++03 standard specifically says the results of this use of `reinterpret_cast` are "unspecified", whereas §3.9/2 specifically allows and guarantees this use of `memcpy`. Regarding depending on the value of `sizeof(unsigned long)`, no it's not the best idea, but that *in no way* implies a failing on the part of using `memcpy`; this is simply a situation where something like `uint32_t` + Boost.Endian is warranted rather than naked `unsigned long`. As an aside, `sizeof(unsigned long)` is `4` on modern MSVC and GCC, even for x64.

Comment: @ildjarn The issue surrounding `reinterpret_cast` is covered by DR 1120.  The issue also turns around §3.10/15, which guarantees that you can access an object through a `char` or `unsigned char` type.  And done correctly, there's no reason to eschew `unsigned long` or add the complexity of boost.  (And I don't have access to an x64 machine at present to verify, but I'm pretty sure that g++ had `sizeof(long) == 8` when I tried it.  Maybe under Windows...)

Comment: @James Kanze : My reading of DR 1120 (and the new C++0x wording) is that whereas before one had to do `static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(&myobj))` in order to get a `char*` to the memory underlying an object *in a well-defined manner*, one may now also do `static_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(&myobj))`. I don't see how that helps in this case, as `static_cast` is still required to get the end result. Re: `unsigned long`, no, there's no reason to eschew it, but it (and assumptions about its size) is a much more likely culprit of potential issues in the OP's code than `memcpy` is.

Comment: @ildjarn I haven't seen the final text which was adopted, so I don't know.  I do know that there was dissatisfaction about the fact that a single `reinterpret_cast` couldn't do what the double `static_cast` does.  In this case, of course, it doesn't matter, since both will result in undefined behavior as soon as you port to a machine where the representation of unsigned long isn't exactly the same as that in his file.  And since at least four representations of `unsigned long` are wide spread (4 or 8 bytes, big or little endian), both solutions are seriously broken.

Comment: @James Kanze : I mostly agree with you, but I don't think we have enough context to state that definitively. What if it's code for a Windows app? `sizeof(unsigned long)` will **always** be 4 in MSVC and the platform will always be little-endian. In that circumstance, does it *really* matter? At least `memcpy` has well-defined behavior in that circumstance, unlike `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: @ildjarn There are two "variables" in the equation: the representation of an `unsigned long` on his platform, and the representation of the integer he is trying to read in the file.  **If** he knows that the code will never be used other than on Windows, he knows the internal format.  If that corresponds exactly to the documented format, he can get away with either the `reinterpret_cast` (because regardless of how you interpret the standard, it works with MSVC) or `memcpy`.  I just hope his crystal ball is working, though.